# what are object and property exactly and can something be both of them

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties

How to tell when a piece of code is an object and when it's property.

### What are object and property exactly and how they relate each other?

---

From here is what confused me, bit of insignificant

[onine course original words from Codecademy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSYol.png)

```
...
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
}, ...
```

here it says: the `"scripts"` **property** contains an **object** with one **property** called `"test"`.

> `"scripts"` property contains **an object with one property called "test"**.
>
> `"scripts"` is a **property**
>
> `"test"` is a **object** with one **property**
>
> `"echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"` is a **property**

or

> `"scripts"` property contains an object, with **one **property** called *"test"***.
>
> `"scripts"` is a **property**
>
> `{...}` is a **object**
>
> `"test"` is a **property**

```
...
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "build": "babel src -d lib"
}
```

here it says: In the `"scripts"` **object** above, we add a **property** called `"build"`. The **property's value** is `"babel src -d lib"`

> `"scripts"` is a **object**
>
> `"build"` is a **property**
>
> `"babel src -d lib"` is the value of a **property**

To me the second code explanation makes a lot more sense but which one is true..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the first explanation is closer to the truth. Let's take a look at the following JSON snippet first:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "build": "babel src -d lib"
}
```

This is the snippet you provided. However, it's not a complete JSON block as this would need braces around it:

```
{
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "build": "babel src -d lib"
    }
}
```

The whole thing now is a JSON object. This object has a property called "scripts". The value of this property is another object containing two properties "test" and "build" with their respective values "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" and "babel src -d lib".

Comment: ohhh Thank you so much. now I see, object doesn't have to have a name as well right? and property's value can be a object as well! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

To understand this you need the full data structure, take the following structure:

```
{
    "child" : {
        "childs_property": "childs_property_value"
    }
}
```

1. `child` is a property in the overall JSON structure which points to an object.
2. `child_property` is a property in the `child` object.

So while `child` is a *property* (of the overall structure) is an object too if you go deeper.

**JSFiddle**

Run [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gauy1ubo/1/) fiddle and check the console an take a look at the output:

```
object
object
string
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D I can get it without the complete structure! also thank you a lot on that Fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    foo: {
        bar: 'some string'
    }
}
```

If you look at the code above:

The whole code block is an "object"
`foo: { ... }` is a property, whose value, `{ ... }`, is an object.
In there,
`bar: 'some string'` is a property, whose value, `{ ... }`, is ***not*** an object. It's a string.

---

To summarize,

- "object": a value of the "object" type, so `{}`, with or without properties.
- "property": a key/value pair on a property.

Comment: Thank you!  It makes a lot of sense when the block is completed.